# Stuck print jobs

Tags: printing, hp, cups-lpd

How do I fix print jobs getting stuck in the queue and never printing?

I have an HP Color LaserJet CP1518 connected to my network. I used to be able to print on Ubuntu 12.10 perfectly. It auto-detected the printer on the network and just worked "out of the box".

Now when I print, I can see the job sitting in the job queue, but nothing ever happens. The printer is still detected and is listed as "On" in the Printer dialog.

I've tried restarting the CUPS service and turning the printer on and off, but nothing helps.

How do I diagnose this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps in order:

1. Cancel all your current documents.
2. If one of them doesn't cancel, pause the job
3. Unplug your printer, wait 30 seconds, plug it back in.
4. Then restart your computer.

If this doesn't work,check to see if the printer is showing any errors. You may have to reconnect the printer to the network, just follow the manufacture/Ubuntu's instructions.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the print troubleshooter:**

```
Click System Settings | Printers,
Then Server | Settings,
Click the blue "Problems?" link.
```

This opens the printing troubleshooter.  It tells you what to fix.

Probably you will just have to check the Enabled property.

Fixed it for me!